How do I use angular-oauth2-oidc library in spartacus SSR mode?
We have enabled SSR and BFF pattern implemented between our storefront and SAPCC. So all our Occ requests goes through our BFF. We have implemented the whole authentication on server.ts (Express) file. Auth token is stored on express session and is appended in a header before it reaches SAPCC.
Is it a good practice?
Also we wanted to know whether we can use this angular-oauth2-oidc library to achieve authentication in server.ts file?
